# Excel VBA combining consecutive numbers

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've never posted to the forum before so I apologize if I break any forum etiquette. I've tried searching both this forum and a general internet search for this answer, but can't find what I'm looking for.

I have two columns of numbers, both formatted as #-#. Essentially, the first number is a chapter number and the second is a section number. If, in both columns, the sections are a  consecutive range, I need it to combine them. For example:

```
2-16 | 2-31
2-17 | 2-32
2-18 | 2-33
2-30 | 2-55
```

Would become:

```
2-16--2-18 | 2-31--2-33
2-30       | 2-55
```

I'm sorry for the formatting. I've tried delimiting by the hyphen and writing a code that checks all four rows at once, but I can't seem to figure out how to have it check through the sections to find when they stop being consecutive. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Interesting problem, and on the surface looks like something that is do-able with VBA. Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Is it the formatting (sort of a page break in your example) but curious 2-30 -- 2-33 is not a valid sub result? right?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an interesting question so I tried something myself. I am just a new learner, and I don't know whether my code is efficient enough or not, but I tested it and it worked.

```
Private Sub Combine()
    Dim i, j, m, n As Integer
    Dim LookStart, SvaeStart As Range
        'Assume the data stored in column A, Cells A2:A9
        'Put the results in Column B,starting with cell B2
    Set LookStart = Range("A2")
    Set SaveStart = Range("B2")
    i = 0
    j = FindEnd(LookStart)
    m = 0
    Do
        n = FindNext(LookStart.Offset(m, 0))
        SaveStart.Offset(i, 0).Value = LookStart.Offset(m, 0).Value
        If n <> 0 Then
            SaveStart.Offset(i, 0).Value = SaveStart.Offset(i, 0).Value & _
                                           " -- " & LookStart.Offset(m + n, 0).Value
        End If
        m = m + n + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop While m <= j
End Sub

Private Function FindEnd(ByVal start As Range) As Integer
    FindEnd = Range("A1").Offset(Cells.Rows.Count - 1, _
                          start.Column - 1).End(xlUp).Row - start.Row
End Function

Private Function FindNext(ByVal start As Range) As Integer
    Dim i, j, flag, CurrentNum, LastNum As Integer
    Dim CurrentText As String
    i = 0
    j = FindEnd(start)
    flag = 0
    Do
        CurrentText = start.Offset(i, 0).Text
        If i <> 0 Then
            If LastNum + 1 <> Left(CurrentText, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", _
                          CurrentText) - 1) * 100 + Right(CurrentText, 2) Then flag = 1
        End If
        LastNum = Left(CurrentText, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", _
                       CurrentText) - 1) * 100 + Right(CurrentText, 2)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While flag = 0 And i <= j
    If flag = 0 Then FindNext = i - 1
    If flag = 1 Then FindNext = i - 2
End Function
```

And the result look like this:

Column A | Column B

2-16   |   2-16 -- 2-18

2-17   |   2-30

2-18   |   2-32 -- 2-34

2-30   |   2-56 -- 2-58

2-32   |   2-60

2-33

2-34

2-56

2-57

2-58

2-60

---

Is there anyone could help me to improve my code? Really really thanks!

Hope this could help you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in a named range - in this case "ChaptersAndSections"..

```
For Each rCol In Range("ChaptersAndSections").Columns
    With Range(rCol.Address)
        For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
            sValue = .Rows(r).Value
            sValue2 = .Rows(r).Value
            If Not r + 1 > .Rows.Count Then
                Do While CInt(Mid(.Rows(r + 1).Value, InStrRev(.Rows(r + 1).Value, _
                  "-") + 1)) = CInt(Mid(sValue2, InStrRev(sValue, "-") + 1)) + 1
                    sValue2 = .Rows(r + 1).Value
                    .Rows(r + 1).Delete shift:=xlUp
                Loop
            End If
            If sValue <> sValue2 Then .Rows(r).Value = sValue & "--" & sValue2
        Next r
    End With
Next rCol
```

Should go without saying, but be sure and test this on a copy of your worksheet as I only tested it with the small data set you provided in your example..